# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un VARCHAR PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Necesito saber cómo puedo obtener el valor de un `VARCHAR`, no como un carácter, si no como su contenido. Me explico mejor:

```
NOMBRE VARCHAR2 (30) := 'JMARTINEZG','JPOLANIA';
select * from DOCUMENTOS D WHERE D.NU_ANO_CALENDARIO = '2016'
AND D.ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA IN (NOMBRE)
```

Tengo un `Query` al cual le debo pasar una variable `VARCHAR` nombre, el cual, contiene `'JMARTINEZG','JPOLANIA'` y necesito que se ejecute con un `IN`.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar y espero me haya dado entender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Sql Server y PostgreSql se puede armar la consulta en una variable y luego ejecutarla. Seria algo asi:

**PostgreSql PLSQL**

```
$BODY$
DECLARE

lcSQL character varying;
Nombre  text;
BEGIN

Nombre:= 'JMARTINEZG','JPOLANIA';
lcSQL:='select *from DOCUMENTOS D
WHERE D.NU_ANO_CALENDARIO = ''''2016''''
AND D.ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA IN (' || Nombre  || ')';

EXECUTE (lcSQL);

END;
$BODY$
```

**Sql Server**

```
Declare @Nombre as VARCHAR (30) 
declare @lcSql as text

Set @Nombre= 'JMARTINEZG','JPOLANIA';
set  @lcSql='select *from DOCUMENTOS D
WHERE D.NU_ANO_CALENDARIO = ''''2016''''
AND D.ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA IN (' + @Nombre  + ')'

Exec( @lcSql)
```

Comment: y para el caso de PL/SQL, ya lo trate de ejecutar y nop ninguna de las dos opciones???..

Comment: Que trataste de ejecutar?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrias hacer es crearte una tabla temporal con 1 o 2 campos COD, NOMBRE y insertarlos en la tabla temporal, lo que primero tendrias que hacer es tener una funcion que separe la cadena por algun caracter la funcion f_split realiza esto y te devuelve un pipelined.

```
  FUNCTION f_split (p_list VARCHAR2, p_del VARCHAR2 := ',')
      RETURN split_tbl PIPELINED
   IS
      l_idx     PLS_INTEGER;
      l_list    VARCHAR2 (32767) := p_list;
      l_value   VARCHAR2 (32767);
   BEGIN
      LOOP
         l_idx := INSTR (l_list, p_del);

         IF l_idx > 0
         THEN
            PIPE ROW (SUBSTR (l_list, 1, l_idx - 1));
            l_list := SUBSTR (l_list, l_idx + LENGTH (p_del));
         ELSE
            PIPE ROW (l_list);
            EXIT;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;

      RETURN;
   END f_split;
```

Ahora deberas de insertar a la temporal

```
insert into tmp SELECT ROWNUM numfila, COLUMN_VALUE nombre
                FROM TABLE (f_split (p_cadena, p_separador));


select * from DOCUMENTOS D WHERE D.NU_ANO_CALENDARIO = '2016'
AND D.ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA IN (SELECT NOMBRE FROM TMP);
```

y eliminar los valores de la temporal si ya no los necesitaras.

Parece una forma larga pero es efectiva, si es multiusuario lo que debes realizar puedes agregar un campo con la sesion en la base de datos y eliminar los datos solo para esa sesion.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes Nombres "JMARTINEZG" y tambien "JPOLANIA", puedes asi:

```
SELECT *
FROM DOCUMENTOS D
WHERE D.NU_ANO_CALENDARIO = '2016'
AND D.ID_LOGIN_USUARIO_ACTUALIZA = @NOMBRE
```

Despues (pseudocode):

```
@NOMBRE = "JMARTINEZG"
```

-o:

```
@NOMBRE = "JPOLANIA"
```

Comment: como podria evaluar esto, debido a que esta varible llega como parametro de un  procedimiento, me enviar un String con varios nombres

Answer (score 0):

Saludos,

Para este caso particular te recomendaría utilizar un cursor dinámico que se construya en tiempo de ejecución:

```
Declare
  Type type_cursor Is Ref Cursor;
  cu_query     type_cursor;
  lc_query     Varchar2(500);
  lc_campo_1   DOCUMENTOS.codindic%Type;
  lc_campo_2   DOCUMENTOS.valindic%Type;
  lc_campo_3   DOCUMENTOS.desindic%Type;

  lc_valores   Varchar2(50) := '''JMARTINEZG'', ''JPOLANIA'''; -- ¡Cuidado con el manejo de las ' simples!
Begin
  lc_query  := 'Select campo_1, campo_2, campo_3';
  lc_query  := lc_query||' From   DOCUMENTOS D';
  lc_query  := lc_query||' Where  D.nu_ano_calendario = ''2016''';
  lc_query  := lc_query||' And    D.id_login_usuario_actualiza In ('||lc_valores||')';  
  dbms_output.put_line(lc_query); -- Output para controlar la ejecución de la consulta armada.
  Open cu_query For lc_query;  
  Loop
    lc_campo_1 := Null; 
    lc_campo_2 := Null;
    lc_campo_3 := Null;
    Fetch cu_query Into lc_campo_1, lc_campo_2, lc_campo_3;
    Exit When cu_query%NotFound;
    dbms_output.put_line(lc_campo_1||' - '||lc_campo_2||' - '||lc_campo_3);
  End Loop;
End;
```

Para esta solución solo deberías tener muy en cuenta el manejo de las comillas simples (') al momento de generar la consulta (ya que esto se vuelve mucho de ensayo y error), para esto te recomiendo utilizar un output del query armado y verificar que este se encuentre en sintaxis bien armado.

Answer (score 0):

En PL/SQL armas la consulta dinámicamente como se muestra en el ejemplo de PostgreSql que muestra @ariel-octavio-dalfeo en su respuesta y luego lo ejecutas con el comando [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm), que se usa precisamente para ejecutar sentencias SQL contenidas dentro de una cadena.